# Swift 3: How to load images dynamically and pass variables to the second view controller?

Tags: xcode, swift3, uiimageview, uitableview

I am trying to load images from a URL to load on the table view dynamically. I am able to load the text but need to load the images. In my external database table, I have 3 columns (id, Name and image) and able to fetch the Name field. The image fields contains the name of the file (myimg.png). I have a url (www.xyz.com.au/images/(image_name_from database.png). So when the table loads, each cell should displays the thumbnail image and the Name. When we press the cell to go to the other View Controller, the ID associated with it should fetch all the records on the second view controller.

Thanks for your help and time in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use image loader to load image into UIImageView. I recommend to use [KFSwiftImageLoader](https://github.com/kiavashfaisali/KFSwiftImageLoader)

```
let imageView : UIImageView!

imageView.loadImage(urlString: imageURL)
```